# Bitbake fails on do_package_qa error?

Tags: embedded-linux, bitbake, gumstix

I am trying to write my own custom recipe. I am using Yocto Project with Bitbake.

The following package when given `bitbake apriltags` commands does the following and throws error at `do_package`

It successfully does the following tasks:

```
do_fetch
unpack
do_compile
```

and then fails at `do_package`

In my `/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apriltags/0.1-r4/git/build/lib` there is a `pkgconfig.pc` and `libapriltags.a` which is causing the error.

My package recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Apriltags application" 
SECTION = "examples" 
LICENSE = "CLOSED" 
PR = "r3" 

DEPENDS = "opencv"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/zafrullahsyed/apriltags.git;protocol=https;tag=v0.1"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig autotools

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/git/build/bin/apriltags_demo ${D}${bindir}
}
```

My error as follows:

```
ERROR: QA Issue: package apriltags contains bad RPATH /home/zaif/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apriltags/0.1-r3/git/build/lib in file /home/zaif/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apriltags/0.1-r3/packages-split/apriltags/usr/bin/apriltags_demo
ERROR: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/zaif/yocto/build/tmp/work/armv7a-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/apriltags/0.1-r3/temp/log.do_package.21621
ERROR: Task 10 (/home/zaif/yocto/poky/meta-bebot/recipes-bebot/apriltags/apriltags_0.1.bb, do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My package Apriltags has bad dependencies that are according to PC in AprilTags/cmake/pods.cmake such as Eigen3(default), whereas for OE eigen3 package is libeigen. Hard coded the requires, Libs and Cflags and also removed python pod packages which are not required.

pods.cmake:

```
"Name: ${pc_name}\n"
        "Description: ${pc_description}\n"
        "Requires: ${libeigen}\n"
 #       "Version: ${pc_version}\n"
        "Libs: -L\${bindir} ${pc_libs}\n"
        "Cflags: -I\${bindir} ${pc_cflags}\n")
```

My recipe is as follows:

```
DESCRIPTION = "Apriltags application" 
SECTION = "examples" 
LICENSE = "CLOSED" 
PR = "r5" 

DEPENDS = "opencv"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/zafrullahsyed/apriltags.git;protocol=https;tag=v0.3"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig autotools

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/git/build/bin/apriltags_demo ${D}${bindir}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Apriltags` has dependencies which need to be modified according to the machine you are working on.

You need to have the values of the `requires`, `Libs` and `Cflags` accordingly. Also verify whether you need the `python pod packages` or not.